# Problem re-adding the same fields to start with a lowercase letter when updating

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, nest, elasticsearch-5

I am encountering a problem while updating. The problem I'm having is, for example, I want to update the Title field, but I see that a new field has been created for the Title field in the document. (A title field that starts with a lowercase letter). I'm doing the update process with NEST, can anyone share an idea with me? Thank you in advance for your help.

**The state of the document before the update:**

```
      {
        "_index" : "my_test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "uPggFnoBChFNLIc8qdjW",
        "_score" : 31.908756,
        "_source" : {
          "RelatedPassiveCompanyId" : "0d075c1681106286cfe9f31999f8247c",
          "CreateTime" : "2021-06-16T21:41:17.2697847+03:00",
          "Title" : "FE NEW CENTURY INDUSTRY(SINGAPORE)PTE LTD",
          "IsBannedFromOpenCorpCompanies" : false,
          "CreatedBy" : 1,
          "IsActivated" : false,
          "IsCancelled" : false,
          "IsMembershipTypeBought" : false
        }
      }
```

**The state of the document after the update:**

```
      {
        "_index" : "my_test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "uPggFnoBChFNLIc8qdjW",
        "_score" : 26.380388,
        "_source" : {
          "RelatedPassiveCompanyId" : "0d075c1681106286cfe9f31999f8247c",
          "CreateTime" : "2021-06-16T21:41:17.2697847+03:00",
          "Title" : "FE NEW CENTURY INDUSTRY(SINGAPORE)PTE LTD",
          "IsBannedFromOpenCorpCompanies" : false,
          "CreatedBy" : 1,
          "IsActivated" : false,
          "IsCancelled" : false,
          "IsMembershipTypeBought" : false,
          "isBannedFromOpenCorpCompanies" : false,
          "contactInformations" : {
            "contactPerson" : { },
            "phones" : [ ]
          },
          "isCancelled" : false,
          "dnbInformation" : {
            "processId" : "fba921ee-493d-4f12-aa0a-0a432b9e8b3a",
            "requestLogs" : [
              {
                "requestTime" : "2021-11-23T10:03:09.8302661+03:00",
                "message" : "Company not found on Dnb",
                "resultType" : 2
              }
            ]
          },
          "createTime" : "2021-06-16T21:41:17.2697847+03:00",
          "createdBy" : 1,
          "isMembershipTypeBought" : false,
          "isActivated" : false,
          "title" : "FE NEW CENTURY INDUSTRY(SINGAPORE)PTE LTD",
          "relatedPassiveCompanyId" : "0d075c1681106286cfe9f31999f8247c"
        }
      },
```

**my update function:**

```
public bool UpdateDocuments(IHit<MyESModel> documentHitItem)
        {
            var response = elasticClient.Update<MyESModel, object>(DocumentPath<MyESModel>
                .Id(documentHitItem.Id), u => u
                .Index("my_test_index")
                .Doc(documentHitItem.Source)
                .DocAsUpsert(true)
                .RetryOnConflict(8)
            );
            return response.IsValid;
        }
```

I would be very happy if anyone has any idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Can you also how the content of `documentHitItem.Source` in your question?

Comment: The content of documentItem is the elastic version of the document. So I'm getting the document from elastic and I want to update it with its document id by changing some of its values.

Comment: Can you print it out in your application logs just before sending it back ?

Comment: "By default, NEST assumes field names should be camelCase as is common for JSON documents" could the problem be related to this?

Comment: Most probably yes !!!

Comment: okay I solved problem thanks for reply:)